# Javascript regular expression nothing to repeat error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to replace a string with another string in Javascript and using the answer given in [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression) by Eric Wendelin - code is the following:

```
var re = new RegExp(delim, 'g');
return input.replace(re,",");
```

When i run this i get the error

> /***/: Nothing to repeat

(the value of delim is "***" btw)

I understand if you get a Nothing to repeat error it means you haven't properly escaped a character in your regexp but why do i get this error in this case ?

Comment: `*` is a token that means "repeat the previous". And there is nothing to repeat, exactly as the message says.

Comment: Did you meant to match 3 asterisks? Because then use `/\*{3}/g`

Comment: could you please add the expected behaviour here ?
that is a sample string and replaced string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is the reserved repetition character, that matches 0 or more times the previous character or group, so you need to escape it (equivalent to `{0,}`).

Change the delimeter string to `\\*\\*\\*` or `\\*{3}`.

```js
delim = '\\*{3}'
input = 'hello *** world'
var re = new RegExp(delim, 'g');
console.log(input.replace(re, ","))
```

Comment: great, thanks for clarifying that